# Using static utility with decorator pattern

Tags: java, static, decorator

I don't know Spring, however to understand some of the java patterns I was reading through Spring tutorials and stumbled onto below code. By the look of it, this looks like classic decorator, but then you see  `ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(this.addressValidator, customer.getAddress(), errors);`. I am somewhat uncomfortable using utility to delegate to the other validator since I feel it would be difficult to unit test these static invocations(although it can be achieved with PowerMock but am not a big fan of the same). I feel `addressValidator.validate()` is pretty much cleaner.Since I am writing a custom validator for one my applications, I just wanted to get some thoughts on these approaches.

```
public class CustomerValidator implements Validator {
    private final Validator addressValidator;

    public CustomerValidator(Validator addressValidator) {
        this.addressValidator = addressValidator;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Customer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "field.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "surname", "field.required");
        Customer customer = (Customer) target;
        try {
            errors.pushNestedPath("address");
            ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(this.addressValidator, customer.getAddress(), errors);
        } finally {
            errors.popNestedPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply mock the AddressValidator. The static utility method, except logging and null checks, doesn't do anything other than calling the AddressValidator.

Comment: Ok, do we really need ValidationUtils - would not just using addressValidator.validate() suffice here?

Comment: The utility method only adds logging, and a check that the AddressValidator supports the class of the object it's asked to validate. So, if you don't care about that, you can use the addressValidator directly.